# how to make a constructor and have it create a (0,0) point?

Tags: java, constructor

How can i make a no arg constructor that creates a (0, 0) point? as in an X and Y point in java? 
Note: I know the code is not complete and might have some mistakes just please help me with the constructor bit
Thanks in Advance

```
public class MyPoint {
public static void main(String[] args) {
private double X;
private double Y;
private String name;
public static int numberOfCreatedPoints;

MyPoint() {
X = 0;
Y = 0;
name = "center";
}

MyPoint (double XCoor, double YCoor, String pointName){
    X = xCoor;
    Y = yCoor;
    name = pointName;

public double getX() {
    return X;
}  

public double getY() {
        return Y;
    }

public String name() {
        return name;
    }
public static getNumberOfCreatedPoints() {

    }
 }
   }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Answer (score 0):

Your class should look something like this:

```
public class MyPoint {
  private double X;
  private double Y;
  private String name;

  MyPoint() {
    X = 0;
    Y = 0;
    name = "center";
  }

  //getters and setters ...

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  }
}
```